# Как убрать повторения в combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Попалась такая проблема, как-то что в combobox повторяются элементы. Элементы с combobox взяты с таблицы. Выглядит так:

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].DefaultView;
            comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Преподаватель"
```

Сама же проблема выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал кое-что, но оно выдает ошибку. Вот строчка:

```
 comboBox.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().SelectMany(i => i).Distinct();
```

Вот скриншот ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как можно решить такую проблему? Может способ, который я написал рабочий просто не так использую?

Comment: Почему вы работаете с UI, а не данными? Вот вы взяли данные `Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].DefaultView`, дальше их задали как источник данных `.ItemsSource =`, UI это отобразил, ок. Так почему не фильтровать данные, а не UI? И да, почитайте про привязки, WPF без проивязок и XAML смысла использовать нет.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь `DataRow` скастовать в `string`, конечно из этого ничего не выйдет. _Может способ, который я написал рабочий_ - нет, даже не близко. В вашем случае `ICollectionView.Filter` можно прикостылись, но лучше использовать привязки, как советует мудрый человек выше.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я использую {Binding Преподаватель}, но почему, то без кода . Она не работает.

Comment: @kanejons2 Ну вот советую разобраться почему, а не делать костыли, которые в реальном проекте вы не увидите. Для привязки нужно 3 вещи: 1. Установить `DataContext` тому, где будет задана привязка (обычно устанавливают окну и этого достаточно) на объект, который будет содержать в себе свойства для привязки (например `DataContext = new MySuperClass();`. 2. Сделать **публичное свойство** в том классе, который задан как `DataContext` с нужным типом (например `public string Name {get;set;}`).3 Указать в XAML эту привязку (прим: `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}" />`). Готово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во, я накостылил :), например так:

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = Connection.ds.Tables["Кружок"].Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(dr => (string)dr["Преподаватель"])
    .Distinct();
```

Но лучше такие проблемы решать раньше, на этапе запроса в базу данных.

Comment: Спасибо, я и так уже исправлю. Так как читал что для бд используют отдельные столбцы для ФИО. Но для проверки с другой таблицей там нужно объединять поля.